# Display formatted JSON (Big Object) in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to display formatted JSON in an HTML page but I'm having some trouble when it comes to larger objects (an array of objects).

Currently I am displaying the JSON object using `JSON.stringify(data)` when I receive the response from the server. My PHP is returning the results as an Array with `json_encode($response)` and I am displaying the results.

As you can see from the sample response below, it displays correctly when it comes to smaller objects.

If the results from the server is greater, I still receive the results (dumped to console with console.log(data), but when `$('#apiResult').append(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));` gets executed, it takes a long time or most often the browser just hangs.

I guess my question would be if there is a more efficient way of doing this or am I doing something wrong?

The reason I want to display it in browser is because I'm creating an API tester tool for a local application.

Thanks for the help in advance.

**Sample Response:**

```
{
  "posted_data": {
    "anything sent": "",
    "etc...": ""
  },
  "server_datetime": "2019-10-19 19:05:36",
  "ip_address": "7.28.185.248",
  "cookies": []
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function executeAPI() {
  var method = $('[name=apiMethod]').val();
  var sendData = {};
  if(method == 'post' || method == 'put') {
    sendData = $('[name=apiBody]').val();
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: $('[name=apiMethod]').val(),
    url: apiObj.baseURL + $('[name=apiPath]').val(),
    data: sendData,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend: function(){
      $('#apiResult').removeClass('text-primary text-danger').html('Request sent, waiting for response...');
      $('#btnApiRequest').prop('disabled', true).text('Please wait...');
    }
  })
  .done(function(data,responseText,jqXHR) {
    $('#apiResult').empty();
    $('#apiStatus').html('<b>Status:&nbsp;<span class="text-success">'+jqXHR.status+' - '+jqXHR.statusText+'</span></b>');    
    if(typeof data === 'object' && data !== null) {
      $('#apiResult').append(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));
    } else {
      $('#apiResult').html(data);
    }
  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
    $('#apiStatus').html('<b>Status:&nbsp;<span class="text-danger">'+jqXHR.status+' - '+jqXHR.statusText+'</span></b>');
    if(jqXHR.responseJSON === undefined) {
      $('#apiResult').html('...');
    } else {
      $('#apiResult').html(jqXHR.responseJSON);
    }
  })
  .always(function() {
    $('#btnApiRequest').removeAttr('disabled').html('Send Request&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-send"></i>');
  });
}
```

Comment: how big is *Big* - does `$('#apiResult')[0].textContent = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2)` work any better?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to display the data on the client-side (and don't need to manipulate it), you should not parse it at all. Treat it as plain text:

```
$.ajax({
  // ...
  dataType: "text", // replace "json" with "text"
  // ...
}).done(function(data,responseText,jqXHR) {
  // ...
  $('#apiResult').append(data);
  // ...
})
```

If you want it indented, server-side you can use `json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`, but as @Bravo mentioned, it would make the response even bigger.

> On a side note, if the response is so big that it makes the browser hang, the issue might not be the one you posted, but the way you designed your API. Do the results contain large Arrays? If so, you might want to consider result pagination.

Comment: indenting server-side would make a *Big* response *Bigger* :p

Comment: @Bravo Yes it would ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It was an observation, not a criticism :p

Comment: I figured that out :)

Comment: I did some more testing and I believe there is a maximum size of data that `JSON.stringify` can handle.